# How to slice the file path in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python as well a programming, and I would like to slice the folder path. For example, if my original path is:

```
C:/Users/arul/Desktop/jobs/project_folder/shots/shot_folder/elements/MexicoCity-Part1/
```

I would like to get the path like this:

```
C:/Users/arul/Desktop/jobs/project_folder/shots/shot_folder/
```

What are the methods of doing this in Python?

Comment: Have you tried anything? [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) helps you with asking questions, so that the community is glad to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to split on `elements`, then use this.

```
>>> path = 'C:/Users/arul/Desktop/jobs/project_folder/shots/shot_folder/elements/MexicoCity-Part1/'
>>> path.split('elements')[0]
'C:/Users/arul/Desktop/jobs/project_folder/shots/shot_folder/'
```

One drawback of this approach is that it'll fail if you encounter the word `elements` in your path multiple times. In that case, you can do something like:

```
>>> '/'.join(path.split('/')[:-3]) + '/'
'C:/Users/arul/Desktop/jobs/project_folder/shots/shot_folder/'
```

Assuming you know the depth of the path you need.

Comment: @arul Cheers. Consider marking this answer if it helped, and close the question. :)

Comment: Take a look at my solution @arul

Comment: This answer shouldn't be accepted . @Coldspeed what if the path has a different file seperator? Can be \  or  /

Comment: Okay, you have a valid point. But can you please refrain from browbeating here? This is not a competition to see who can get the most upvotes. In the last 10 minutes you have made over 3 comments explaining why my answer is trash. Alright, you are contributing to a collective knowledge base, not racing at the derby. Please behave accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @s_vishnu Also I should mention hiro protagonist's answer is the best one here.

Comment: Truth spoken. But sometimes it's good even great to be competitive. And i see in many posts related to python and that gave me a push. In a way it is making me a little positive. hope you take it in that way too :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146354/discussion-between-s-vishnu-and-coldspeed).

Comment: @s_vishnu That's all right, I've said all I need to. :x

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module:

```
from pathlib import Path

pth = Path('C:/Users/arul/Desktop/jobs/project_folder/shots/shot_folder/')

print(pth)
print(pth.parent)
print(pth.parent.parent)  # C:/Users/arul/Desktop/jobs/project_folder
```

The module has a lot more of very convenient methods for handling paths: your problem could also be solved using [`parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) like this:

```
print('/'.join(pth.parts[:-2]))
```

In Python 2.7 you could build your own `parts` function using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html):

```
from os import path

pth = 'C:/Users/arul/Desktop/jobs/project_folder/shots/shot_folder/'

def parts(pth):
    ret = []
    head, tail = path.split(pth)
    if tail != '':
        ret.append(tail)
    while head != '':
        head, tail = path.split(head)
        ret.append(tail)
    return ret[::-1]

ret = path.join(*parts(pth)[:-2])
print(ret)  # C:/Users/arul/Desktop/jobs/project_folder
```

Comment: thank you hiro, but want this to be done in python 2.7.13 .

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
folder = 'C:/Users/arul/Desktop/jobs/project_folder/shots/shot_folder/elements/MexicoCity-Part1/'

folder.rsplit('/', 3)[0]
```

`str.rsplit()` basically returns a list of the words in the string, separated by the delimiter string (starting from right).

Please have a look at [documentation](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html) for more details on this method.